# Learn more about the nature of a constraint?

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

A piece of legacy code I'm running that does some oracle SQL is violating a constraint called REF_REQUEST.

I look up this constraint by doing:

```
select * from all_constraints where constraint_name='REF_REQUEST'
```

This tells me that the constraint_type is 'R', and it gives me the table name of CORRESPONDENCE.

However, I still don't know... what value I'm missing from CORRESPONDENCE, or where I'm trying to insert that is causing the issue, and what column is relevant from each. How can I learn this information by querying the dB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `get_ddl` method in `dbms_metadata` package to get more details about the constraint

```
SELECT CAST(DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('CONSTRAINT','REF_REQUEST','CERTIFICATION') AS VARCHAR2(4000)) 
FROM DUAL
```

That should tell you what columns the constraint is acting on

---

One of the overloaded methods accepts the schema name, so you can pass it as a parameter.

```
DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL (
object_type     IN VARCHAR2,
name            IN VARCHAR2,
schema          IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
version         IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'COMPATIBLE',
model           IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'ORACLE',
transform       IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'DDL')
RETURN CLOB;
```

Further reading:

- Oracle documentation on [dbms_metadata.get_xxx subprograms](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm#BABFBDDG)

Comment: That gives me an error: ORA-31603: object "REF_REQUEST" of type CONSTRAINT not found in schema "My_login". Probably because I don't own this table, CERTIFICATION does. How do I change the syntax to reflect that?

Comment: Thanks, but I still can't make it work. I supplied the owner as the schema name and it's still not found. If I go with Dcookie's solution, I get: CERTIFICATION REF_REQUEST CORRESPONDENCE ID 1 for owner, name, table_name, column_name, and position, so the constraint is there... I just can't quite figure out how to use your method. Is there some different schema I should be providing? Or something else?

Comment: `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('CONSTRAINT','REF_REQUEST','CERTIFICATION')` *should* work. If you go by Dcookie's method, is this the only row that's being retured? @Jeremy

Comment: That's exactly what I did and it didn't work. And yes, it is the only row being returned.

Comment: @Jeremy strange - I'll check it out once I'm at my workstation, don't have access to a Oracle instnace

Comment: @Jeremy I just tested this, it works fine. Perhaps your login doesn't have `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` [grant](http://sshailesh.wordpress.com/2010/05/08/dbms_metadata-get_ddl-avoid-ora-31603-error-by-using-select_catalog_role/)?

Comment: @Sathrya that seems likely. It's a simple read-only account. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you know it's a referential integrity constraint based on your select from all_constraints (constraint_type = R), so you can just query all_cons_columns for your answer:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name
  FROM all_cons_columns
 WHERE constraint_name = 'REF_REQUEST'
 ORDER by position;
```

Comment: Very easy and works very well, thanks. I guess "all_cons_columns" is the table I'm looking for when I need more information.

Comment: Well, it's very specific - it only tells you the columns involved in the constraint. Depending on what you need, the GET_DDL function may help you more.